# Can I apply for US driver's licence when visiting for a couple of months with J-1 visa?

Tags: usa, driving-licenses, j1-visas

I am visiting Illinois for a couple of months with J-1 visa for work and I could use a driver's licence, but I do not have one. I am wondering if I would be eligible to apply for one.

What I have already figured out is that there are three types of licenses: (1) Regular driver license, (2) Temporary visitor driver's license, (3) Non-visa status applicant temporary visitor driver's license. I found that options (2) and (3) require at least 12-month stay in the US, so I am not eligible. But as far as I can find, there do not seem to be limitations in the regular option (1).

Just to clarify, I am a foreign citizen visiting with J-1 visa. I have a US social security number, rental contract, utility bills, US bank account, etc (I have lived in US before). I do not have a driver's licence from any country.

Comment: Do you have a driving licence in your home country?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps would be useful to edit into your question for clarification.

Comment: If you do not have a license from anywhere, you will almost certainly have to pass the test.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk as I understand it, RealID compliance requires states to verify immigration status, for which a SSN is insufficient.  This implies that either your state is not compliant or the requirements have changed since you last looked at them.

Comment: @phoog, I guess my state of California is one of the 26 States that is not RealID compliant. http://www.latimes.com/travel/deals/la-tr-spot-20160214-story.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you could, but not in every state.  From [US Immigration and Customs Enforcement website](https://www.ice.gov/doclib/sevis/pdf/dmv_factsheet.pdf):

> **Who is eligible for a driver’s license or ID?**
>
> Any F, M or J nonimmigrant in lawful status may apply for a driver’s
>   license or ID card, per state or territorial law. The nonimmigrant
>   must present necessary supporting documents required to verify legal
>   presence in the United States. For a list of required documents, see
>   What documentation must a nonimmigrant present to the DMV? [...]
>
> [...]
>
> **When can a nonimmigrant apply for a driver’s license or ID?**
>
> Please be aware of the following timing requirements before applying
>   for a driver’s license or ID:
>
> - The Student and Exchange Visitor Information System (SEVIS) record must be in  Active status when an F, M or J nonimmigrant applies for a
>     benefit. A  nonimmigrant with a record in any other status will not
>     have success applying for a benefit.
> - Wait at least ten calendar days from the date of entry into the United States before applying for a driver’s license or ID to allow
>     time for arrival data processing. [...]
> - Wait at least two federal business days from the activation date in SEVIS to apply for a driver’s license or ID to ensure that the
>     nonimmigrant’s Active  status updates in all relevant databases.
> - Several states require that a nonimmigrant have at least six months left on the Form I-20, “Certificate of Eligibility for Nonimmigrant
>     Student Status,” or Form DS-2019, “Certificate of Eligibility for
>     Exchange Visitor (J-1) Status,” to be eligible for a driver’s license.
>     Either consult with the state or territory’s DMV or visit its website
>     to see if this is a requirement.

In your case it's down to the last point: do you need at least 6 months remaining on your visa in the state where you live?

**EDIT:** To find out whether you need the 6-months validity on your visa, simply contact your local DMV or call IL Department Of State Driver Services:

- Springfield: 217-782-6212
- Chicago: 312-814-2975

Anecdotally, [this forum posts](http://forums.immigration.com/threads/il-drivers-license-j-1-visa-expires-within-6-months.315969/) alludes that you *do* need the 6-months validity.

Comment: Thanks! This confirms what I thought. Unfortunately, it still does not answer my question. Any idea where to find information about specific states, i.e. Illinois in my case? I spent a while browsing Illinois DMV website, but could not find the info.

Comment: @TomH I updated my answer.  The simplest thing is to call the DMV - I added Illinois numbers for you.

Comment: If the Illinois BMV is anything like the Indiana BMV, you'll have to have a lot of patience on the phone. It will take them a while to figure out something like this.

Comment: Thanks! I called to Chicago DMV and they told me that if I already have a SSN, then the 6-month requirement does not apply. I guess I'll give it a try and update the post for future reference later.

Comment: @TomH Great! Certainly update your post with your actual experience.

Comment: Just an update: apparently in Illinois you can get a driver's licence when you already have SSN even if your visa expires quite soon. However, the expiration date of the driver's licence will be the same as the expiration date of the visa, which may make it somewhat less useful.

Answer (score 3):

For Illinois, nformation regarding driving licences for immigrants with permanent resident status **or** a nonimmigrant visa is available [here](http://www.illinoislegalaid.org/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.dsp_content&contentID=8425). The relevant conditions for your status appear to be:

> - Are an alien lawfully admitted for permanent or temporary residence
> - Have a valid, unexpired nonimmigrant visa or nonimmigrant visa status

To get an Illinois Driver's license you must:

> - Visit a Driver Services Facility, show your identification, and have
>     your photo taken;  To find the Driver Services Facility near you, see
>     the Secretary of [State Facility Finder](http://icirr.org/content/what-new-driver%E2%80%99s-license-law-means-sb-957);
> - Pass the vision, written, and driving tests;
> - Pay the [Fee](http://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/departments/drivers/basicfees.html).

This [site](http://www.dmv.org/il-illinois/apply-license.php) also gives relevant information and a list of the [documentation](http://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/publications/pdf_publications/dsd_x173.pdf) that must be provided. Note that two documents proving residency must be provided.

Neither of those sites appear to list a minimum residency period.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a Driver's license if you're just visiting for a couple months.

An international driver's license will do, and most often your own country's driver's license is all you need to rent a car. The international driver's license is only a translation of your driver's license in a bunch of other languages, and is meant to be presented with the actual license.

Comment: I know this, but it does not work, as it would require having a driver's licence from some other country.

Comment: well if you don't have a license, that's a different question.